# ¿Cómo concatenar o combinar números de varias columnas en una sola sin perder los ceros que hay a la izquierda?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

En [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) tengo 9 columnas (desde la `B` hasta la `J`) y dentro de cada una de ellas tengo valores numéricos de dos dígitos cada uno.

En la columna `K` quisiera producir automáticamente una cadena o un número que sea la combinación de esos 18 valores **sin perder los ceros que están a la izquierda**. Lo importante es que el resultado tenga los 18 dígitos que hay.

Lo he logrado con esto:

```
=TEXT(B4;"00")&TEXT(C4;"00")&TEXT(D4;"00")&
 TEXT(E4;"00")&TEXT(F4;"00")&TEXT(G4;"00")&
 TEXT(H4;"00")&TEXT(I4;"00")&TEXT(J4;"00")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera saber si no hay otra forma más simple de hacerlo.

Comment: Qué formato usas de B-J?

Comment: @lois6b un formato numérico de dos dígitos:  `00`. Los valores entre `B-J` son números que me interesa tener formateados a dos posiciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("";TEXT(B2:J2;"00")))
```

## Explicación

- TEXT es una de las funciones que acepta rangos como argumento.
- ArrayFormula hace que los resultados se extiendan a las celdas que requiera el resultado de la función que contiene.
- JOIN concatena valores. Una alternativa a este es TEXTJOIN.

Comment: Rubén no  me funciona: `Error de análisis de fórmula.`

Comment: @A.Cedano Cambia las comas en la fórmula por punto y coma o la configuración de tu hoja de cálculo, por ejemplo a México :)

Comment: Lo hice, yo debo usar `;` siempre... aún así no funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de copiar la fórmula a mi hoja de cálculo y funciona. ¿Me compartes tu hoja de cálculo? (cualquiera con el enlace)

Comment: Ahora sí, es que había puesto `;` también en el separador de rango y por eso daba error. Ahora funciona: `=ArrayFormula(JOIN("";TEXT(B13:J13;"00")))`. ¡Gracias!, buscaba justamente algo así, sabía que existiría.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que la manera más simple de generar una cadena con los valores es con la formula concatenar

```
=CONCATENATE(B2:J2)
```

Comment: Amigo (nunca mejor dicho :-) ), yo probé eso, pero el problema es que no me guardaba los valores de dos dígitos de cada columna, me daba resultados como: `11114111`. Trate de combinarlo con `TEXT` para que rellene los `0` a la izquierda, pero no di con una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Cambiar el formato de las columnas B:J a Texto sin formato haría que  Concatenate funcionara. Pero depende de si puedes y te conviene hacer ese cambio.

Comment: No, porque yo necesito que allí sean números.

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(TEXT(B2:J2,"00")))`  es 4 caractares más largo que `=ArrayFormula(JOIN("";TEXT(B2:J2;"00")))` pero también funciona :)